# Обтекание текста под углом

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такое обтекание текста под углом?

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

```css
.block{  
  overflow: hidden;  
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.pict{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
  -webkit-shape-margin: 10px;
  shape-margin: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="pict"></div>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
</div>
```

или

```css
.block{  
  overflow: hidden;  
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.pict{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-shape-margin: 10px;
  shape-margin: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="pict"></div>
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
</div>
```